# Stopping EJB's being loaded by the container

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I have a data access EJB project that has a number of EJB's I want to use this module across a number of projects to make use of some common classes however, I don't always want the EJB's in the project to be loaded. More specifically I only want certain EJB's to be loaded for certain projects. Other than splitting the projects in to multiple EJB modules and have the common classes in a core library is there anything I can do.

Most of the EJB's in the project at @Singleton and initialised @Startup.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James, I think I do understand want you want to achive, but this does not make sense to me. If you want to share certain classes without sharing the EJBs itself, you should create a *Utility JAR* containing those classes you want to share. This is not only a workaround, but a best-practice as it decouples things.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen or heard of the ability to selectively load EJB's that belong to the same EAR.

If this is really a requirement, perhaps you can include only your shared libraries and boilerplate code (like a DAO) in the common project and refactor the individual data access facades into the projects they're referenced by.

Comment: I guessed that would be the answer but thought I would find out for sure first, thanks.